# how to get id of people who reacted to a reaction in discord.py

Tags: python, list, discord, discord.py

I'm using this code to get a list of people who reacted to the reaction

```py
    new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(id)
    users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    users.pop(users.index(client.user))
    if ctx.author in users:
      users.pop(users.index(ctx.author))
```

but I want it to return id's of people who reacted to it so after that I could use a command like this

```py
user =  bot.get_user(userId)
await ctx.send(user.created_at)
```

and find out that how many user's account is older than n days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID is a field in the user object according to the [discord-py Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User.id).

So you can just do `[user.id for user in users]` to get the list of IDs.
But since you want the user objects anyways, you can

```py
for user in users:
    await ctx.send(user.created_at)
```

Comment: and is there any way where I can find out how old is a user's account "In Days", basically what am I doing here is, asking for the author to add a requirement in a command that'll specify how old should the account be to react to this message,  I can get the date when an account is created , but I cant figure out how to get that in days

Comment: `user.created_at` returns a datetime.datetime object. So you can take `timespan = datetime.now() - created_at` and then `timespan.days`